# How to serialize a dataframe in django? Is there a way to return dataframe along with queryset in django?

Tags: python, django, pandas, dataframe, django-pandas

What I'm trying to do here is get a query based on users' choices like date, group, and symbol.

I would like to convert this queryset to a data frame using django_pandas.

I tried to convert the data frame generated to JSON object but it gives some errors like:

> TypeError: Object of type 'DataFrame' is not JSON serializable

My viewset looks like this:

```py
class StockPriceDataViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                     viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = StockPriceData.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StockPriceDataSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter]
    filterset_fields = {
        'date':['gte','lte'],
        'org__symbol':['exact'],
        'org__group':['exact'],
    }
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    
    @action(methods=['GET'], detail=False, url_path='stock')
    def get_df(self, request):
        queryset = self.queryset
        result = generate_df(queryset=queryset)
        return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

```py
def generate_df(queryset):
    df = queryset.to_dataframe()
    df = df.drop(['s_n','id'], axis=1)
    # df = df.set_index(['org','date'])
    result = df.to_json(orient='records', date_unit='ms', 
    lines=True).splitlines()
    return result
```

When I run the above code in an interactive shell it runs smoothly without any errors but when Django handles the request an error pops up:
`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_json'`

Also, the format of JSON is not standard as I was expecting.
What am I doing wrong here? Can anyone explain? Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT2: Removed the `get_queryset()` method as it was not doing anything here. Added the @action method for retrieving the data frame.

Here is another problem, the JSON object returned is not of the queryset that I initially fed the function. The filter set fields are not working as they were supposed to work. Every time I try to get the specific data frame, the data frame of the whole database is returned instead of that specific query. What must be the easiest solution?

EDIT: Stack Trace added:

```
AttributeError at /api/v1/stock/price/
'tuple' object has no attribute 'model'

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/v1/stock/price/?page=1
Django Version: 3.0
Python Executable: /home/anjaan/project/fintech/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.8.5
Python Path: ['/home/anjaan/project/fintech', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/anjaan/project/fintech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time: Wed, 17 Feb 2021 05:49:42 +0000
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'drf_yasg',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework.authtoken',
 'rest_framework_swagger',
 'rest_framework_jwt',
 'rest_auth',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'django_extensions',
 'django_rest_passwordreset',
 'django_filters',
 'channels',
 'users',
 'misc',
 'notification',
 'finance']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'fintech.middleware.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'fintech.middleware.UserActivityLogMiddleware']


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anjaan/project/fintech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/anjaan/project/fintech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/anjaan/project/fintech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/anjaan/project/fintech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/anjaan/project/fintech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/anjaan/project/fintech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/anjaan/project/fintech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/anjaan/project/fintech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/anjaan/project/fintech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/anjaan/project/fintech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 38, in list
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
  File "/home/anjaan/project/fintech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 150, in filter_queryset
    queryset = backend().filter_queryset(self.request, queryset, self)
  File "/home/anjaan/project/fintech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_filters/rest_framework/backends.py", line 90, in filter_queryset
    filterset = self.get_filterset(request, queryset, view)
  File "/home/anjaan/project/fintech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_filters/rest_framework/backends.py", line 31, in get_filterset
    filterset_class = self.get_filterset_class(view, queryset)
  File "/home/anjaan/project/fintech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_filters/rest_framework/backends.py", line 73, in get_filterset_class
    class AutoFilterSet(self.filterset_base):
  File "/home/anjaan/project/fintech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_filters/rest_framework/backends.py", line 74, in AutoFilterSet
    class Meta(MetaBase):
  File "/home/anjaan/project/fintech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_filters/rest_framework/backends.py", line 75, in Meta
    model = queryset.model

Exception Type: AttributeError at /api/v1/stock/price/
Exception Value: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'model'
```

Comment: Please share the entire stack trace

Comment: I updated the stack trace after @Abdul 's answer. Please have a look.

Comment: @Anjaan let us know if you got it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Django REST Pandas. here is the documentation https://pypi.org/project/rest-pandas/

Answer (score 0):

You write:

```
df = df.set_index(['org','id'],inplace=True)
```

The `inplace=True` means you want to make the changes to the same object, due to this the method returns nothing causing `None` to be stored in `df`. Change the line to either of the below:

```
df.set_index(['org','id'], inplace=True)
```

OR

```
df = df.set_index(['org','id'])
```

Comment: Ok I did that and it is now showing another error:
```'tuple' object has no attribute 'model'```
I tried to convert to json like this: 
```df.to_json(orient='records', lines=True).splitlines()```

Comment: @Anjaan `get_queryset` is not supposed to return a `tuple` it is supposed to return a queryset, you need to override some other method.

Comment: Ok what can I override to return a dataframe serialized JSON object to use in another function?